# In Android, How can i use Youtube Player with indicator?

Tags: android, youtube-api

In my project, i use youtube player.

my project is shopping app, i set youtube player in ViewPager.
It's perfect. no problem. however, my client want add circle indicator.

I can't understand, it has problem.
I add indicator in my XML file, youtube player play just one second. i click play, one sec play and stop again. What happen???

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMusicPlayer"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_music" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="260dp">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="260dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicators"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

that's my activity xml code. 
I insert lower xml to ViewPager by lower code.(ViewPager Adaptor)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <view
        android:id="@+id/video_viewpager_childvideo"
        class="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and it's ViewPager Adaptor.

```
    view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_viewpager_child_video, null);

    final YouTubePlayerView video = (YouTubePlayerView) 
    view.findViewById(R.id.video_viewpager_childvideo);
    String fullurl = mediaUrls.get(position).getUrl();
    YouTubeHelper youTubeHelper = new YouTubeHelper();

    final String videoUrl = youTubeHelper.extractVideoIdFromUrl(fullurl);

    listener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, 
    YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            youTubePlayerInstance = youTubePlayer;
            youTubePlayer.cueVideo(videoUrl);
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
     YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        }
    };

    video.initialize(youTubeApiKey, listener);
```

if i remove me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator, perfectly work.
if just change two view's position, it works too.

me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator is just now try. i try 4 kind of insicator, anyone has problems.
one time I add just View for some black shadow, it has problem too.

this.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMusicPlayer"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_music"
        android:onClick="onClickMusic" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="260dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_down" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I cant understand, why btnMusicPlayer dosen't make error??
I think youtube player has problem when some view over that. isn't it?

Please help me!!

Comment: Yes you can not add any view over player.

Comment: @Pankaj Kumar real? but some apps using indicator over youtube!

Comment: Can you please give name of those? And there is a super solution of it but I am not sure how you will do it with pager.

Comment: @Pankaj Kumar i heard(my boss say. i don't use it) instargram use circle indicator over the youtube in android. and he say some apps using this system.

Comment: There are many apps which does like that but they do not use youtube player. Facebook and Instagram have their own players

Comment: @Pankaj Kumar your right. youtube player can't overlap. 
I found a very very strange solution... only Button (btnMusicPlayer) can overlap the youtube player. it's not under in XML, but front. I think use many button can do everything, but it may be not good solution.

Comment: look for PopupWindow. This is only solution for it. Design controls and show as popupwindow, it will not affect the youtube terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read your logcat you'll see that you cannot have views overlapping the YouTubePlayer, that's why it stops.

You have to alternatives:

1. Remove the overlaying View.
2. Use a WebView-based implementation, like [android-youtube-player](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player).

Comment: oh, i can't understand why i didn't see logcat before....
I must see that after.
now, my boss understand it's impossible and remove overlapping indicator.

he say instargram do it, but i see that, instargram didn't use overlap indicator... he say sorry.... why i waste a month....?

Comment: @Redwings I doubt Instagram is using the YouTube player. Remember to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this](https://medium.com/@soffritti.pierfrancesco/customize-android-youtube-players-ui-9f32da9e8505) is what you're looking for. It will allow you to use custom UI for the API. It is an open source library intended to be used as a replacement for the official YouTube Android Player API.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Note: This library does not use native player, it uses iframe (webview) for player.

Comment: Yes, but it will give you the tools to customize and that is what you need. Additionally, it does not require YouTube to be on the device. Unless you MUST use the native player I highly recommend trying this out.

Comment: This is slower than the native one. And I don't think there would be any Android Phone without YouTube App. But here I am not against to use this library, I just wanted to highlight drawback of this library

Comment: @PankajKumar You win customization but lose a bit of speed. A fair trade I think. Kindly accept this as the answer if it helps you. :)

Comment: thanks for your help. I talk to my boss, he understand it's impossible in now situation. when another project meet this problem, i'll use this. thanks.

Comment: @Redwings Glad to help. Upvote and choose as an aswer please :)